# Do CascadeType.ALL and "insertable = false, updatable = false" exclude each other?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

If I have the configuration like this, can it work?

```java
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinColumn(name = "FOREIGN_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
ForeignClass foreignClass;
```

I think not, because the behaviour of the cascade types is in conflict with the insertable and updatable parameters.

What do you think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They mean different things and do not conflict with each other.

So given the following mapping :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="player")
public class Player {


   @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
   @JoinColumn(name = "team_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
   Team team;

}
```

- `cascade` means that when using `EntityManager` to `persist()` or `merge()` on a `player` , JPA will **automatically** call `persist()` / `merge()` on this player 's team  too.
- `insertable` and `updatable` is about if allow to assign a new team or update the team for a player . In term of the DB table , it is about if the value of `Player` table 's `team_id` column is allowed to be inserted or updated.

So one is about inserting/updating records in the `Team` table while another is about inserting/updating the value of the `Player` table 's `team_id` column , which are totally different things.

Answer (score 3):

Long story short, no, these settings do not exclude each other.

Imagine, we have the following model.

```sql
create table APP_USER
(
   USER_ID number,
   USER_NAME varchar2(400),
   
   constraint APP_USER_PK primary key(USER_ID)
);

create table APP_BILLING_NUMBER
(
   BILL_ID number,
   BILL_ACCOUNT varchar2(20),
   BILL_BANK_NAME varchar2(300),
   BILL_USER_ID number,
   
   constraint APP_BILLING_NUMBER_PK primary key(BILL_ID),
);
```

And appropriate hibernate mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "APP_USER")
public class User
{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "USER_ID")
   private Long id;
   
   @Column(name = "USER_NAME")
   private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "APP_BILLING_NUMBER")
public class BillingNumber
{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "BILL_ID")
   private Long id;
   
   @Column(name = "BILL_ACCOUNT")
   private String account;
   
   @Column(name = "BILL_BANK_NAME")
   private String bankName;
   
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="BILL_USER_ID")
   private User user;
}
```

If we try to do something like this:

```
  User user = new User();
  user.setId(1L);
  user.setName("Alex");
      
  BillingNumber bill = new BillingNumber();
  bill.setId(1L);
  bill.setAccount("EA12345678");
  bill.setBankName("BNP Paribas");
  bill.setUser(user);
      
  session.persist(bill);
```

We will find out that the bill was added to the `APP_BILLING_NUMBER` table,

```
SQL> select * from APP_BILLING_NUMBER;
BILL_ID BILL_ACCOUNT BILL_BANK_NAME BILL_USER_ID
------- ------------ -------------- ------------
1       EA12345678   BNP Paribas    1
```

but the user was not. It happened because by default we have `@ManyToOne(cascade={})`. If we want to persist a `User` entity with a `BillingNumber` entity we should add `CascadeType.PERSIST`:

```java
  @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
  @JoinColumn(name="BILL_USER_ID")
  private User user;
```

then, if we are going to use `session.merge(bill)` operation we should add `CascadeType.MERGE` as well.

Now imagine, we have

```java
  @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
  @JoinColumn(name="BILL_USER_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private User user;
```

After executing the above persist operation we will have:

```
SQL> select * from APP_USER;
USER_ID USER_NAME
------- ---------
1       Alex

SQL> select * from APP_BILLING_NUMBER;
BILL_ID BILL_ACCOUNT BILL_BANK_NAME BILL_USER_ID
------- ------------ -------------- ------------
1       EA12345678   BNP Paribas    (null)
```

As you can see, both entities were inserted but the `APP_BILLING_NUMBER.BILL_USER_ID` reference is `null` because of `@JoinColumn(..., insertable = false, ...)`. And you can not update it because of `updatable = false`.

So, this is valid but quite exotic case.